# Javascript fails in IE when developer tools are closed

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm debugging my site and when I don't have console open something isn't working and is failing javascript. But when I'm doing same things with developer tools open there suddenly isn't any problems...

How can I see what kind of error occurred if I can't use developer tools?

Comment: use developer tools...that's why it is there. alternatively you can pop up alert boxes, or try chrome developer tools, or firebug to get another perspective, but most likely you're just missing something about how dev tools works.

Comment: @Timmerz As I said, everything works with developer tools, Steve Fenton already gave answer to this. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you close developer tools, there is no longer a `console` attached, so `console.log(...)` will fail.

Look in your code for use of `console` and wrap it in a check:

```
if (typeof console !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('Message');
}
```

You could extract this into a function to save typing it everywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much, all time fastest answer to my question :D

Comment: I remember having the exact same problem with Firebug :) http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201102/Blog/JavaScript-Only-Works-When-Firebug-Is-Open/

Comment: Because I have very complex site I needed to add like 40+ `console.log` to track if everything is going correctly and why is something failing. Thanks again! Never thought to look that direction... As soon as I can I will accept your answer. :)

Comment: You can add this on the top of the script to: `if (!window.console) window.console = function() {};`, so no exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: turned out I'd used `console.log` in my code which was failing when the console was closed.

In your code, you can simply check that the `console` object exists before using `console.log`.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very vague explanation, but perhaps there is some kind of race condition with your javascript, and some events are happening in different orders when you have the developer tools open. (assuming that your code isn't failing because of console not being defined)